# Drag and drop em uma listagem no cakephp

Tags: php, html, cakephp

Tenho que fazer uma ordenação através dos métodos de arrastar e soltar.
Gostaria de saber de que forma poderia utilizar isso no cakephp?

O problema é o seguinte:
Tenho diversos registros retornados em uma listagem, gostaria de arrastar por exemplo, o 5º registro para o 1º e efetivar que este seja gravado no banco com prioridade 1, assim o que estava em 1º passa a ser 2º e assim sucessivamente.

Alguém poderia me ajudar com uma ideia de como fazer e o que posso utilizar para fazer isso?

Obrigado.

Comment: Para reorganizar itens com drag and prop você vai ter que usar javascript, aconselho o sortable do Jquery-UI http://jqueryui.com/sortable , a partir daí você pode salvar a nova ordem por ajax ou fazer toda reorganização e depois salva-la.

Comment: Obrigado, irei estudar sobre isso.